# Error while adding JavaFX files in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, javafx

I installed eclipse plugin *e(fx)clipse* to work with *JavaFX* and created a new JavaFX project. In the *Package Explorer* the project structure looks like this:

[image]

Further I'm trying to add to the project *JavaFX Main Class*:

[image]

[image]

But this causes the following error in IDE:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2018-03-05 17:05:55.276
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.xtend2.lib.StringConcatenation.append(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at org.eclipse.fx.ide.jdt.ui.internal.wizard.templates.ApplicationClassGenerator.generateContent(ApplicationClassGenerator.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.fx.ide.ui.wizards.AbstractNewJDTElementWizard.performFinish(AbstractNewJDTElementWizard.java:165)
...
```

and the same error occurs when I'm trying to add *New FXML Document* from *JavaFx section*. It seems that it's [eclipse IDE bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=525746)... But how to get round it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you installed the pre-bundled Eclipse SDK with JavaFX 8 you need to update eclipse via Help->Check for Updates.

That solved the issue for me.